# Is an Identity Column Sufficient for Achieving Logical Replication in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, aws-dms

I have a PostgreSQL table `A` on AWS RDS which is not partitioned. I want to migrate the data to `B` which is partitioned by `hash(user_id)`.

*Table `A` doesn't have any PK or unique index.*

I am using AWS DMS for this task. DMS provides *Full Load with CDC or Ongoing replication* which uses logical replication.

*For, logical replication to work Postgres requires a PK or Unique Index.*

As I have a partitioned table, I have to have composite PK/Unqique index which will always have `user_id` as a part of it and I want to avoid that.

I am thinking to create an identity column on `A` and the same on `B`.

But, I am not sure whether `Identity Column` will work with logical replicaiton.

Here are the tables,

```
CREATE TABLE A_source (
    user_id text NULL,
    agency text NULL,
    "location" text NULL,
    id bigint generated always as identity
);

CREATE TABLE B_target (
    user_id text NULL,
    agency text NULL,
    "location" text NULL,
    id bigint generated always as identity
)
PARTITION BY HASH (user_id);


CREATE TABLE B_target_1 PARTITION OF B_target
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 0);

CREATE TABLE B_target_2 PARTITION OF B_target
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 1);

CREATE TABLE B_target_3 PARTITION OF B_target
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 2);

CREATE TABLE B_target_4 PARTITION OF B_target
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 4, REMAINDER 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, identity column can be used as primary for logical replication in postgres. Identity column can be created in both source and target tables.try using this code;

```
-- Source Table A
CREATE TABLE A_source (
    user_id text NULL,
    agency text NULL,
    "location" text NULL,
    id bigint generated always as identity
);

-- Target Table B (Partitioned)
CREATE TABLE B_target (
    user_id text NULL,
    agency text NULL,
    "location" text NULL,
    id bigint generated always as identity
) PARTITION BY HASH (user_id);
```

For data integrity, make sure that the identity column values are distinct inside each partition.  The identification column should be included in the replication process when configuring logical replication using AWS DMS.